# Update Java program on Mac

Tags: java, macos, shell, auto-update

I have my Java program which runs on Mac. Jar file is packaged into *.app and that *.app is installed into /Applications folder on Mac.

Now, I have added auto-update functionallity to the program like Skype has.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaZHE.png):[[image]]
and can't finish this auto-update functionallity for Mac OS.

How it should work:

1. Program checks an xml available by specific url
2. If there is new version of software then
3. Program downloads *.zip archive with new version in /tmp folder (/Users/Shared/tmp)
4. Unpack *.zip in /tmp
5. Rename new version of program from 'program-name' to 'newprogram-name'. It was made since I can't copy file with 'program-name' to /Applications because such program exists and is running now.
6. Copy 'newprogram-name' from /tmp to /Applications
7. Remove curent running 'program-name'
8. Rename 'new' (located in /Applications) to
9. Run . Now it will be new version of program

Steps 1-6 I can do from running Java program
Steps 7-8 I can not do since program can't remove itself from disk when it is running.

In order to achieve these 7-9 steps I have written a script which can do steps 7-9.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir tmp-dir

while [[ $(pgrep myapp-process | wc -l) -ne "0" ]]; do
    echo "myapp is Running"
    sleep 3s
done
    echo "myapp has been Stopped"

rm -rf /Applications/myapp.app

mv /Applications/newmyapp.app /Applications/myapp.app

chmod -R 755 /Applications/myapp.app

open /Applications/myapp.app
```

So, theoretically I just need to run this script from Java program before exiting - System.exit(0); like this

```
String macTmpFolder = properties.getProperty(ConfigConstants.MAC_TMP_DIR);

        String command = "sh "+macTmpFolder+"/ak-restart.sh";

        logger.debug("Shell command is:"+command);

            try {
                //Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(macTmpFolder+"/ak-restart.app"));
                Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }

            System.exit(0);
        }
```

But in practice it doesn't work from Java since 'rm' command requires 'sudo' rights. It is not an option to add config to 'sudoers' file. If I run script manually it works.

I'm not expert in Mac OS and unix based systems. I have no idea how to make this restart of new version of program working. Will appreciate any help with it. Or maybe someone knows another way how to do auto-update feature on Mac OS with Java program packaged in *.app